# Maven dependency can't find zip file for sendgrid-java

Tags: java, maven, grails, gradle, sendgrid

I am getting an error while trying to include sendgrid-java during the build of a grails project.

I've added a compile time dependency as described in the documentation:

```
compile 'com.sendgrid:sendgrid-java:2.1.0'
```

But when I try to build it, it fails to resolve the dependency.  I can see it is trying to download this zip file from mavenCentral, but it does not exist:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java/2.1.0/sendgrid-java-2.1.0.zip

If I browse to the parent directory I can see many similar files but no .zip file.  How can I get it to resolve the dependencies without the expected zip file?  Can you tell gradle to use just the .pom file instead?  I'm stuck!

There is lots of useful stuff here in this parent folder, just not zip file and i just can't get gradle to use it:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java/2.1.0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have put this in the `plugins{}` block instead of the `dependencies{}` of your `BuildConfig.groovy`.

`plugins` is for grails plugins, which are distributed as `.zip` files, hence the error message with the file not being found.

"Regular" maven/ivy dependencies are handled just by the `dependencies` block (like in Gradle if you will).

Comment: Thanks!  sendgrid-java is a library not a plugin.  I actually had this in the plugins block, but it was supposed to be in the dependencies block.  This got me on the right track so I'm marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it in the dependencies section of buildConfig.groovy is correct.  It is in the Maven Central repository.  So if you just have mavenCentral() in your repositories section of buildConfig.groovy all should be well.